how to set 4 timers on ATMEGA2560 to output signals
I am using proteus and C language to compile the code.
I have 8 input signals, 4 timers and using it I need to output 4 signals (PF0-PF3).
My pin PF0 refuses to work with T2 timer. I can't understand why and I need to implement two timers more.
PF4 = x1&x3&x5&x7 | x2'&x4'&x6 (works)
PF2 = (x1'|x3'|x5')&T4 (works)
PF0 = ( x1 & !x8 & x2 & !x3 | x7 & !x4 &x 5& x6) & T2 where x1-x8 are PA0-PA7 (doesn't work)
When I set PA0 as zero input signal I get immediately PF0 as zero and vise versa so timer doesn't work.
But if I set PA0 or PA2 or PA4 as 1 I get in 8 seconds PF2 result (timer works).
I also need to calculate PF1 using four timers and reading x1-x8, could you help me to understand where is the error and which the last two timers I need.
Here is code
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define T2 1000UL * 4 // 4 seconds delay
#define T4 1000UL * 9 // 9 seconds delay

void timer2_init()
{
    // Set Timer2 to CTC mode
    TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM22);

    // Set prescaler to 1024 and start timer
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS22) | (1 << CS20);

    // Load the timer counter register
    OCR2A = T2 - 1;

    // Enable Timer2 compare match interrupt
    TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);
}

void timer4_init()
{
    // Set Timer1 to CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);

    // Set prescaler to 1024 and start timer
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);

    // Load the timer counter register
    OCR1A = T4 - 1;

    // Enable Timer1 compare match interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
   if ((PINA & (1 << PA0)) && (!(PINA & (1 << PA7))) && (!(PINA & (1 << PA1))) && (!(PINA & (1 << PA2))) ||
       (PINA & (1 << PA6)) && (!(PINA & (1 << PA3))) && (PINA & (1 << PA4)) && (PINA & (1 << PA5))) {
       PORTF |= (1 << PF0); // Set PF0 to 1 if the condition is met
   } else {
       PORTF &= ~(1 << PF0); // Set PF0 to 0 if the condition is not met
   }
   
   
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    // Check the input signals and set PF2 accordingly
    if (!(PINA & (1 << PA0)) || !(PINA & (1 << PA2)) || !(PINA & (1 << PA4))) {
        PORTF |= (1 << PF2); // Set PF2 to 1 if any of the signals are not set
    } else {
        PORTF &= ~(1 << PF2); // Set PF2 to 0 if all signals are set
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // Set PF0 and PF2 and PF3 as outputs
    DDRF |= (1 << DDF0) | (1 << DDF2) | (1 << DDF3);

    // Set PA0, PA1, PA2, PA3, PA4, and PA5 as inputs
    DDRA &= ~((1 << PA0) | (1 << PA1) | (1 << PA2) | (1 << PA3) | (1 << PA4) | (1 << PA5) | (1 << PA6) | (1 << PA7) );
    PORTA |= (1 << PA0) | (1 << PA1) | (1 << PA2) | (1 << PA3) | (1 << PA4) | (1 << PA5) | (1 << PA6) | (1 << PA7);// Enable internal pull-ups for PA0-PA7

    // Initialize Timer2
    timer2_init();
    // Initialize Timer1
    timer4_init();

    // Enable global interrupts
    sei();

    while (1)
    {
        // Calculate PF3 immediately
        if (((PINA & (1 << PA0)) && (PINA & (1 << PA2)) && (PINA & (1 << PA4)) && (PINA & (1 << PA6)) ) ||
            (!(PINA & (1 << PA1)) && !(PINA & (1 << PA3)) && PINA & (1 << PA5))) {
            PORTF |= (1 << PF3); // Set PF3 to 1 if the condition is met
        } else {
            PORTF &= ~(1 << PF3); // Set PF3 to 0 if the condition is not met
        }
    }
}


I would not read an input port 8 times inside a single if condition. The result could be wrong if the port changes in between. Take a snapshot of the port, store this in a local variable and evaluate this copy. The condition in the code for PF0 does not match the equation in the text.

You need to read the datasheet more carefully. Timer 2 is an 8-bit timer. It's working, but instead of ~4 seconds of delay, it's more like 160 ms. Also, as @Jens says, you need to understand how && and || actually work in C.
